# Query entity relation which is null on mocked Db Context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I'm using [Microsoft docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn314429.aspx) for mocking `DbContext`. I have a problem with querying `IOrderedQueryable` that is null.

```
var report = new Report();
report.DataSource = null;
var q = context.Reports.Select(x => x.DataSource).OrderBy(x => x.Name);
var results = q.ToList();
```

When I call `ToList`, it throws an error in `TestDbAsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync` on this line

```
return Task.FromResult(_inner.MoveNext())
```

Error:

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> at lambda_method(Closure, Experience)
>   at System.Linq.EnumerableSorter`2.ComputeKeys(TElement[] elements, Int32
>   count)
>
>   at System.Linq.EnumerableSorter`1.Sort(TElement[] elements, Int32 count)
>   at System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`1.<GetEnumerator>d__1.MoveNext()
>
>   at S360.Tests.TestDbAsyncEnumerator`1.MoveNextAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)

If I remove `OrderBy` or `OrderBy x => 0` everything works fine. Any solutions how I can mock `DbContext` so that my query does not throw any exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the `Limitations of EF in-memory test doubles` on the Microsoft documentation.

When you project to `.DataSource` in the `Select()`, it is likely this is null, which is causing the NullReferenceException when you try to access `.Name` in the `OrderBy()`.

When you execute this queryable against a database, EF will see the access to the `DataSource` navigation property, and include a `JOIN` so that it is fetched.

When executing in memory, this join does not occur.

You can add the expected `DataSource` entity to the `Reports` entity in your test setup, or better yet use the [Effort in-memory provider](https://github.com/tamasflamich/effort), which will populate the navigation properties, just as a real database would.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I also received an exception related to lambda_method:

```
System.NullReferenceException occurred
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly
  StackTrace:
       at lambda_method(Closure , InspectionAsset )
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.<>c__DisplayClass6_0`1.<CombinePredicates>b__0(TSource x)
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereListIterator`1.MoveNext()
       at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
       at AssetManagement.Model.Repositories.AssetDataService.<LoadOtherAssetsFromTrackAsset>d__18.MoveNext() in C:\src\AssetManagement\AssetManagement.Model\Repositories\AssetDataService.cs:line 135
  InnerException:
```

For me, I was originally building the data like this with the exception happening at `query = query.Where(filter);`:

```
using Nito.AsyncEx;

    // ...

    private static readonly AsyncLock _assetsMutext = new AsyncLock();
    public List<Expression<Func<sset, bool>>> Filters { get; } = new List<Expression<Func<Asset, bool>>>();

    // ...

    public async Task<IQueryable<Asset>> LoadAssetsOnTrack(IList<Asset> trackAssets, List<Asset> assets)
    {
        IQueryable<IAsset> query = null;
        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            using (await _assetsMutext.LockAsync())
            {
                var equipmentList = this.GetEquipment();

                Parallel.ForEach(trackAssets, (asset, state) =>
                {
                    if (!AssetRepository.GetIsAssetTrackType(asset.TypeCode))
                    {
                        var equipment = equipmentList.Where(x => x.AssetID == asset.AssetID).FirstOrDefault();

                        var inspectionAsset = new Asset()
                        {
                            AssetID = equipment?.AssetID,
                            Description = equipment?.Description,
                            // ...
                        };
                        // ...
                        assets.Add(inspectionAsset);
                    }
                });
                query = assets.AsQueryable();

                foreach (var filter in Filters)
                {
                    query = query.Where(filter);
                }
            }
        });
        return query;
    }
```

To eliminate the exception I changed the function to be like this:

```
    public async Task<IQueryable<Asset>> LoadAssetsOnTrack(IList<Asset> trackAssets, List<Asset> assets)
    {
        IQueryable<IAsset> query = assets.AsQueryable();

        foreach (var filter in Filters)
        {
            query = query.Where(filter);
        }
        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            using (await _assetsMutext.LockAsync())
            {
                var equipmentList = this.GetEquipment();

                foreach (var asset in trackAssets)
                {
                    if (!AssetRepository.GetIsAssetTrackType(asset.TypeCode))
                    {
                        var equipment = equipmentList.Where(x => x.AssetID== asset.AssetID).FirstOrDefault();

                        var inspectionAsset = new Asset()
                        {
                            AssetID = equipment?.AssetID,
                            Description = equipment?.Description,
                            // ...
                        };
                        // ...
                        assets.Add(inspectionAsset);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        return query;
    }
```

That said, it still is not totally clear to my why I would sporadically get the exception in the top version of the function and not get it in the bottom version.  If anyone has any further insights please let me know.